# Itemcode is not delete from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am trying to get a row of information to delete from my database 'barcode' but it is not happening. I hit the submit button but it does not delete the 'itemcode' that I have typed in the input box. HELP??

**following edit i have a new error**

> Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

**Delete.php**

```
    Testing to see if items deleted
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td>Item Code: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="itemcode" autofocus></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
</table> <br>

<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');
$txtitemcode = (!empty($_POST['itemcode']) ? $_POST['itemcode'] : null);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from barcode order by itemcode");
$delete = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM barcode WHERE itemcode='itemcode'");
 if(!mysqli_query($con, $delete))
    {
        echo('Error:'.mysqli_error($con));
    }
echo "<center><table border=1>";
echo"<tr>
<th>ITEM CODE:</th>
<th>Company Shipping:</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
echo"<tr>
<td align= center>".$row['itemcode']."</td>
<td align=center>".$row['item']."</td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

**dbconnect.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","db1");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Connected to Database. Please Continue.";
  }
```

**Add.php** The add.php works but delete does not.

```
php

include('dbconnect.php');
function get_posts() {

    global $con;
    $txtitemcode = (!empty($_POST['itemcode']) ? $_POST['itemcode'] : null);
    $txtitem = (!empty($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : null);
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO barcode (itemcode, item) VALUES ('".$txtitemcode."','".$txtitem."')";
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql1))
    {
        die('Error:'.mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "<script> alert('1 record added');
window.location.href='index.php';
</script>";
}
get_posts(); //Must have to show posts in table
mysqli_close($con);
?
```

Comment: Add some mysql error output using mysql_error(). This is not even valid sql: mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM barcode (itemcode) VALUES ('".$txtitemcode."')");

Comment: You do not provide your table structure, but should your SQL statement not read "DELETE FROM barcode WHERE itemcode='$txtitemcode'" (You used the field name 'Name').

Comment: Also, take note of @maxhb's warning about using mysql_error()/ Without checking for errors you are groping in the dark if anything goes wrong.

Comment: So, I need to add  if(!mysqli_query($con, $results))
    {
        echo ('Error:'.mysqli_error());
    } To show whats up?

Comment: @crafter Even with the original statement that shouldn't issue an error - only just not deleting anything.

Comment: My main thing right now is that I need to delete the itemcode / item but if I can not even delete an itemcode then i will not be able to delete the item as well.  basically.... I need to delete in a table the whole row left to right. Itemcode and Item

Comment: `DELET FROM table WHERE col = "value"`  will delete all rows where column "col" has a value of "val" and will not "delete the column" - make yourself familiar with RDBS.

Comment: The statement should be "DELETE FROM barcode WHERE itemcode='$txtitemcode' ". In your updated code, you are trying to delete a record where the value of itemcode is 'itemcode', which probably does not exist.

Comment: Also set the scope of $con ad global, using "global $con;", as you did for the Add.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the stuff twice:

This line executes the query and puts the result in to $delete:

```
 $delete = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM barcode WHERE itemcode='itemcode'");
```

Now you are issuing another query with the result from above:

```
 if(!mysqli_query($con, $delete))
 {
    echo('Error:'.mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

And this is issuing an error as posted: the result in `$delete`  is "1" and "1" isn't a statement.

Change:

```
 $delete = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM barcode WHERE itemcode='itemcode'");

 if(!$delete) // or if ( $delete === false )
 {
    echo('Error:'.mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

Furthermore, following the logic of these few lines, I assume it should be:

```
 if ( isset($txtitemcode) )
 {
     $delete = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM barcode WHERE itemcode='" . $txtitemcode . "'");

     if(!$delete) // or if ( $delete === false )
     {
        echo('Error:'.mysqli_error($con));
     }
 }
```

Comment: This got rid of the error You have an error in your SQL syntax;... But this still is not deleting the itemcode out of the database

Comment: Is there a row with an itemcode equal to the string `"itemcode"`? This is what you are deleting currently. See the comment of 
 
@crafter above

Comment: I have edited my original to show my add.php which does work. So I need to do the opposite of the add....